# Deploy embedded java application on fixed reader zebra FX7500

Tags: java

Application running well in eclipse. while deploying debin package on zebra admin panel getting error application already running can't install again

I created another application with different package name but getting same error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you referring to [FX7500 Fixed RFID Reader](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/rfid/rfid-readers/fx7500.html)?

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _while deploying debin package_ Do you mean [Debian](https://www.debian.org/) ?